# setting font color of button using XML and Java Swing Synth LaF

Tags: java, colors, look-and-feel, foreground, synth

I'm using the Java Swing Synth Look and Feel. I'm able to specify the style of several components. Nonetheless, I'm not able to set the font color of a button for the default state. Text of buttons is always displayed in black, but when focusing/selecting/moving mouse over text color changes to white and afterwards back to black.
Here's a snippet of my synth-XML-file:

```
<synth>
<style id="defaultStyle">
    <font name="Dialog" size="16" />
</style>
<bind style="defaultStyle" type="region" key=".*" />
<style id="button">
   <property key="Button.textShiftOffset" type="integer" value="1"/>
   <state>
      <imagePainter method="buttonBackground" path="./images/JButton/default.png"
           sourceInsets="20 24 20 24" paintCenter="true" stretch="true"/>
      <insets top="20" left="24" bottom="20" right="24"/>
      <color type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" value="#FFFFFF"/>
   </state>
</style>
<bind style="button" type="region" key="Button" />
...
</synth>
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I change the default font color of the button?

Some additional information:

- Java 1.6
- Windows 7, 32-bit

Answer (score 1):

Seems as I managed to fix it. For no known reason I had to use color tye "FOREGROUND".

Comment: Thank you, the javadoc does not specify 'FOREGROUND' is actually text color for Button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<style id="button">
   <property key="Button.textShiftOffset" type="integer" value="1"/>
   <font name="Dialog" size="12"/>
   <state>
      <imagePainter method="buttonBackground" path="./images/JButton/default.png"
           sourceInsets="20 24 20 24" paintCenter="true" stretch="true"/>
      <insets top="20" left="24" bottom="20" right="24"/>
      <color type="TEXT_FOREGROUND" value="#FFFFFF"/>
   </state>
</style>
<bind style="button" type="region" key="Button" />
```

This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/synth/doc-files/synthFileFormat.html) might useful for you.